# Как вытащить слово из теста, введенным пользователем

Tags: php

Ну вот например: У нас есть форма ввода:

```
<input type='text' name='text_user'>
```

И пользователь Ввел такое сообщение:

`Приветик всем :)`

Как вытянуть смайлик `:)` и заменить его на картинку , например такую --> `<img src='Smile_1.jpg'>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть много решений.

Можно просто сделать

```
<?
$string = "Приветик всем :)";
$pattern = ":)"; // тут массив со смайлами в виде текста для замены
$replacement = "<img src='Smile_1.jpg'>"; // тут массив со смайлами в виде картинок
echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Немножко дописать код и вуаля!

Answer (score 0):

Гугли на тему реализации bb code либо на тему парсинга. Один из примеров с описанием можно посмотреть [тут](http://irbis-team.com/15/18).

Answer (score 0):

можно это сделать сразу, javascriptom

```
<input id='text_user' type='text' name='text_user' onblur="set_smiles(this.id, this.value)"/>

function set_smiles(id, value) {
  value = value.replace(':)','<img src="Smile_1.jpg">');
  document.getElementById(id).value = value;
}
```